# C Programming- Splitting a function but last letter is being cut off?

Tags: c, string, c-strings

So I'm trying to do a coding project for a class I'm in and we need to split a code like such ATL1234S15 and I was able to get the first part mostly working except it will only print AT instead of ATL?

Here is my code any help would be appreciated.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(void)
{
    char Code[30];
    char Piece[10];
    int token = 0;

    printf("Enter a product code: ");
    scanf("%s", Code);

    for (token = 0; !(Code[token] >= '0' && Code[token] <= '9'); token++)
    {
        strcpy(Piece, Code);
        Piece[token] = '\0';
    }
    printf("Warehouse: %s ", Piece);
```

Comment: `strcpy(Piece, Code);` - this is copying the entire `Code` into `Piece`. Potentially writing out of bounds too. And it is done in a loop for some reason for each letter, while should only be done once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code currently has a little mistake which causes the issue.

You replace the letter "T" with "\0" because of code: `Piece[token] = '\0';`
You should add "\0" after the letter T.

The corrected code is:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int)
{
    char Code[30];
    char Piece[10];
    int token = 0;

    printf("Enter a product code: ");
    scanf("%s", Code);

    for (token = 0; !(Code[token] >= '0' && Code[token] <= '9'); token++)
    {
        strcpy(Piece, Code);
        Piece[token+1] = '\0';
    }
    printf("Warehouse: %s ", Piece);
    return 0;
}
```

I would also advise you to use iterator as "i", not "token". I believe it would be easier for you to read and understand the code.

Comment: This code has more mistakes. `Piece` should not be reconstructed every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be copying the string in the loop. You can use "isdigit" to test the character, and strncpy to copy only the portion of the string you need.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void main(void)
{
    char Code[30];
    char Piece[10];
    int i = 0;
    
    printf("Enter a product code: ");
    scanf("%29s", Code);

    while (!isdigit(Code[i++]))
        ;   // Loop until a digit is found
    strncpy(Piece, Code, i);
    Piece[i] - '\0';
    printf("Warehouse: %s ", Piece);
}
```